# Month function within Sumif function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I have entered this formula in a cell and press Enter, Excel doesn't accept it.

```
=SUMIF(MONTH($B$2:$B$61);K2;$A$2:$A$61)
```

**Why?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't like this ... MONTH($B$2:$B$61) ... you just can't do it.  Also, you have semi colons between your parameters, you need commas.

Comment: Semicolons are used for functions in my Excel language. I want to know WHY. So I get a better understanding of how functions work.

Comment: Also I tried this and it is not working either:
'=AVERAGEIF(CHOOSE(MONTH($B$2:$B$61);"Q1";"Q1";"Q1";"Q2";"Q2";"Q2";"Q3";"Q3";"Q3";"Q4";"Q4";"Q4");K26;$A$2:$A$61)'

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Skin semi-colons are the same as commas - either is used based on the language and separators chosen in the system settings.

Comment: @SolarMike, yeah, never used them, you learn something new every day.

Comment: All the `xxxIF(S)` functions require ranges, not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUMIF` expects a range.  It doesn't want an array of values, it wants a qualified range.  Adding `MONTH()` around the range turns it into an array of values.

You can see that within VBA, it's explicit as to what it expects.

[image: SUMIF]

That's my take on it ...!

Comment: How do I know what is a Range and what is an Array?

Comment: @Prema Ranges are cells and Array are values. When referring to a range, you type something like A2 or A2:10. Arrays are values like `{1,2,3,4,5}`. You can think about it like ranges mean the *position* of the data and arrays are for the data itself.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns =SUMIF(MONTH($B$2:$B$61)
How can Month() be an Array then? There is a Range written in it.
Now I can evaluate month () with F9 and see the values, but I can do that for the last part in the formula also:
=SUMIF(MONTH($B$2:$B$61);K2;**$A$2:$A$61**)
And that is a Range. How can I see the difference weather it is a Array or a Range?

Comment: @skin I tried Month in vba like you did. worksheetfunction.month, but it seems not even possible to write like that.

Comment: @Prema, I was merely showing you another way to confirm that SUMIF accepts only a range as the first parameter. If you’re using VBA, you still need to provide a range of cells, not an array of values. Even though you have a range in the MONTH() function, you’ve diluted the cell range down to an array of values for the SUMIF function because MONTH doesn’t return a range, it returns a set of values. SUMIF no longer knows about the cells and that’s your problem. The first parameter only accepts a range of cells. Make sense?

Comment: @skin Thank you. I think I got it now.

Comment: @skin I didn't do it first, because the answer was more in the comment then in the answer.

Comment: @Prema, no worries, the entire context will be enough or someone else to understand anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot put MONTH inside of SUMIF. You can replace it with:

```
=SUM((MONTH($B$2:$B$61)=K2)*$A$2:$A$61)
```

Comment: One needs to add that this is an array formula. CTRL+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 2):

Your column C holds the month number, you can use that as criteria range instead of `MONTH($B$2:$B$61)`

Try `=SUMIF(MONTH($C$2:$C$61);K2;$A$2:$A$61)`