# Sum cells that are in current Month in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to calculate MTD (Month to Date) of some products. Let's say my data is

```
   Product   Sale   Date
  A          2     27/01/2022
  B          4     26/01/2022
  A          1     14/12/2021
```

I wish to sum A products that are sold this month. So my Sumifs function have two criteria. I tried use the below formula but it seems the month function is not working. Any tip is greatly appreciated

`=SUMIFS(!B:B,!A:A,"A",!C:C,MONTH(TODAY()))`

Comment: Check this and see if it helps ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754454/month-function-within-sumif-function/70754913#70754913

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just tried some the solutions and unfortunately none of them worked. The VB code looks promising. However, I'm not allowed to add VB in the file.

Comment: Can you add a column next to it that contains the month for each date or are you limited there?

Comment: Not unfortunately, the whole page will be refreshed automatically daily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you may use any one of the following,

**Formula Used In Cell C6**

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($C$2:$C$4)=MONTH(TODAY()))*($A$2:$A$4=B6)*($B$2:$B$4))
```

**Formula Used In Cell D6**

```
=SUM(IF((($A$2:$A$4=B6)*(MONTH($C$2:$C$4)=MONTH(TODAY()))),$B$2:$B$4))
```

**Formula Used In Cell E6**

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$2:$B$4*(TEXT($C$2:$C$4,"MMM")=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMM"))*($A$2:$A$4=B6),,))
```

*Kindly remember you need to increase the range, i have just shown as per the sample data provided, hope it helps*

[image: THREE ALTERNATIVE FORMULA]

Answer (score 2):

A possible option is to create a new column "is todays month" with the formula =IF(NUMBERVALUE(MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(C2))=0,1,0)

Then use =SUMIF(D2:D4,"1",B2:B4)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The sum of sales for product "A" in the current month:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$4,(A$2:A$4="A")*1,(MONTH($C$2:$C$4)=MONTH(TODAY()))*1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. but we need to o increase the range? right?